# How does this moving average functions work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, moving-average

I'm using `d3` to visualize some data.  One of my data sets with the form of:

`[[date, value], [date, value], etc...]` jumps around a lot, and I'd like to incorporated a moving average.

I found this function from Stack Overflow as a solution to calculating moving average, but I don't feel right using it because **(1)** I don't understand how it works, and **(2)**, it doesn't seem to work with my data.

Here's the function (taken from [d3.js moving average with previous and next data values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940475/d3-js-moving-average-with-previous-and-next-data-values/19942056#19942056)):

```
var movingWindowAvg = function(arr, step) {
        return arr.map(function(_, idx) { 
          var wnd = arr.slice(idx - step, idx + step + 1); 
          var result = d3.sum(wnd) / wnd.length; if (isNaN(result)) { result = _; }
          return result;
        });
      };
```

**Line-by-line:**

```
var movingWindowAvg = function(arr, step) {
```

Create a function with the params of a 1D array and a `step` that decides how many values you are using to each individual average point.

```
return arr.map(function(_, idx) {
```

Map the array to (something?), I know `_` is a wildcard operator, like from OCaml, and `idx` is the id?

```
var wnd = arr.slice(idx - step, idx + step + 1);
```

Seems like `wnd` stands for window, so finding the subset of the data to use as an averaging window for the first moving average point.

```
var result = d3.sum(wnd) / wnd.length; if (isNaN(result)) { result = _; }
```

Actually calculating the average.

**Overall**:
I guess my big question is, going through this function, it seems like it's for finding the moving average of a 1D array.  In order to use it, do I have to transform my data into a 1D array, or is there a way to alter the function itself slightly?  I'm having a hard time altering the function because syntactically it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to agree this code is a bit confusing. If I understand correctly it works with 1D arrays? And you'd like it to work with 2D arrays. I'm guessing you would like to have a movingWindowAvg with 'value'.

`.map()` is a function that loops through your array. So for the first loop. `_ = [0,0]` and `idx = 0`, then for the second loop `_ = [1,1]` and `idx = 1`. To get the right value for `_` , all you need to do is `_ = _[1]'`

I made a little conversion function to transform your sliced 2D array `wnd` to 1D array, since I don't really know how d3 works.

isNaN(result) just checks if the result is not a number, and will give it a number _

```
var data = [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3]
];

var movingWindowAvg = function(arr, step) {
        return arr.map(function(_, idx) { 
          _=_[1];
          var wnd = arr.slice(idx - step, idx + step + 1); 
          alert('wnd: ' + wnd);
          var result = d3.sum(to1D(wnd)) / wnd.length;
          if (isNaN(result))
          { 
              result = _; 
              alert('not a res ' + _);
          }
          return result;
        });
};
console.log(movingWindowAvg(data, 1));

function to1D(wnd)
{
    var nwnd = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < wnd.length; i++)
    {
         nwnd.push(wnd[i][1]); //1 to access value   
    }
    return nwnd;

}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/6mNWE/1/